# Where can I find Flash Plugins?

Tags: flash, plugins, adobe, flash-cs3

Are there any plugins for Flash CS3 (or greater) that expand Flash's ability. Actually, i'm sure there are, where can I find them?

EDIT:

Preferably free and from places besides Adobe. (Not that Adobe's bad, but I want variety.)

EDIT2:

I amreferring to extesions, not components, although references to free  component's are also helpful.

Comment: ah. good point. Post as answer. Also, looking for other places too.

Comment: Out of curiousity, are there specific functionalities you're after ? What do you need plugins for ? Also, a bit off topic...extensions is what most things that extend flash's functionality are called although back in flash mx 2004 days, there were plugins(dll files) like DistortFX, PixelFX or TextFX by Red Giant Software, but timeline effects didn't have much of a success, although the Copy To Grid and Distributed Duplicate were quite handy.

Comment: @George Profenza - I have been using Flash CS3 out of the box for a few years and I wanted to know how I can expand it. I'm not looking for anything specific.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean Flash Extensions ?

If so here are a few resources(mostly on animation):

1. [Adobe Flash Exchange](http://www.adobe.com/cfusion/exchange/index.cfm?event=productHome&exc=2)
2. [Dave Logan's extensions](http://www.dave-logan.com/weblog/?p=46)
3. [ToonMonkey extensions](http://www.toonmonkey.com/extensions.html)
4. [Animonger extensions](http://www.animonger.com/flashtools.html)
5. Great and up to date [extensions from AjarProductions](http://ajarproductions.com/blog/flash-extensions/).

If you need something that will declare stage instances, I wrote a [tiny extension](http://www.adobe.com/cfusion/exchange/index.cfm?event=extensionDetail&extid=1860528) for that.

What functionality do you need ?

Comment: What does your extension do that Flash doesn't? I'm slightly confused.

Comment: Flash declares stage instances by default, but when you want to link a class you write to an Actionscript symbol(instead of using the generated empty class from Flash and you have no access to), you will need to manually declare the instances you are going to use in that class. My extension makes it slightly easier, as it writes some of that code for you.

Answer (score 1):

There aren't flash plugins per se (that I know about). Although Flash and Photoshop are merging functionality with each new generation of the CS suite (after the corporate merger of macromedia and Adobe). The flash IDE doesn't currently use "plugins" . If you use FLEX or Air  SDK/builder there are tons of sample applications that extend the flash player libraries.

Comment: What CS are you working with? last I checked there were plugins but I;m looking for non-adobe hosted stuff.

Answer (score 1):

what you are probably thinking of are components, and they are available pretty much anywhere and everywhere. you dump the SWC file into your flash directory (depending on your version) and they appear in the componants tab.
They tend to be pretty specialised or company related (eg. Google analytics/maps etc) so your best way is to search by need. Very few I know of come free.

Comment: I meant "mxp" plugings, or extensions - not SWC. Thanks though.